# Proving that a subset of C is open

Tags: complex-analysis

NOT DUPLICATE - OTHER THREAD DOES NOT HELP AND I CANNOT COMMENT.

I know that there is a thread with this exact question however the answers don't help me write a mathematical proof for it which I am struggling to do. I know what I have to do to prove the statement but I don't know how I would do this in an exam.

I am stuck on how to prove the following:

Prove that

$$
S=\{z∈C:Im(iz)>0\}
$$
is open in $(\Bbb C,d)$.

I know that this is the $Re(z)$ but am struggling on how to write a mathematical proof for this which I can use in an exam.

I know the idea is that you can find a open ball with radius epsilon around every point however I want to know how to write this properly using notation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z=a+ib$ an arbitrary element of $\mathbb C$. Then $iz=-b+ia$, so $Im(iz)=a$. Hence your set $S$ is precisely the set of complex numbers with strictly positive real component.

If $z=a+ib$ is any such element, then trivially $z$ is in the ball centered at $z$ of radius $a/2$. This ball is also a subset of $S$, since the distance of $z$ to the nearest point outside of the set is $a$.

Comment: yes, that was the sort of thing I had. Thanks for confirming with me!